# For loop in R returning null?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called ecr that displays exchange rates of different currencies. I want to write a function that replaces each value (in rupees, pounds, euros, etc.) with the standard deviation from the mean. I wrote this to begin, just for Australia:

```
Aus_sds <- for(i in ecr$Australia) {
(i-mean(ecr$Australia))/sd(ecr$Australia)
}
```

but Aus_sds has a value of NULL. On the other hand, `(ecr$Australia[1]-mean(ecr$Australia))/sd(ecr$Australia)` works fine for any value in the brackets. What am I not understanding about for loops in R?

Comment: It should be `(ecr$Australia[i]-mean(ecr$Australia))/sd(ecr$Australia)` in second line !

Comment: From `?for`: *"'for', 'while' and 'repeat' return 'NULL' invisibly"*. Never assign a `for` loop to a variable (unless you always always always want that variable to `NULL`, in which case you should shortcut the ambiguity and just do `Aus_sds <- NULL`, since that's what is happening.)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your intention is to capture a vector of values (z-scores).

1. `for` loops return `NULL`. Always. Invisibly. So `anyvariable <- for (...) { ... }` will always be `NULL`.
2. *In general*, one can use `sapply` to do what you need:

   ```r
   sapply(mtcars$disp, function(x) (x - mean(mtcars$disp)) / sd(mtcars$disp))
   #  [1] -0.5706 -0.5706 -0.9902  0.2201  1.0431 -0.0462  1.0431 -0.6779 -0.7255 -0.5093 -0.5093  0.3637
   # [13]  0.3637  0.3637  1.9468  1.8499  1.6886 -1.2266 -1.2508 -1.2879 -0.8926  0.7042  0.5912  0.9624
   # [25]  1.3658 -1.2242 -0.8909 -1.0943  0.9705 -0.6916  0.5670 -0.8853
   ```
3. However, *in this case*, you can take advantage of R's vectorization:

   ```r
   (mtcars$disp - mean(mtcars$disp)) / sd(mtcars$disp)
   #  [1] -0.5706 -0.5706 -0.9902  0.2201  1.0431 -0.0462  1.0431 -0.6779 -0.7255 -0.5093 -0.5093  0.3637
   # [13]  0.3637  0.3637  1.9468  1.8499  1.6886 -1.2266 -1.2508 -1.2879 -0.8926  0.7042  0.5912  0.9624
   # [25]  1.3658 -1.2242 -0.8909 -1.0943  0.9705 -0.6916  0.5670 -0.8853
   ```

   *No `for` loop required.* The `mean(...)` and `sd(...)` calls will reduce to a single value each, so that's equivalent to `(x - mu)/sigma`, where `x` is a vector and each of `mu` and `sigma` are scalars.

And voilà, you have your z-scores.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could avoid many functions using `scale()`. Lets show the concept with `mtcars` data. This function does what you want, centering variables respect to mean and make values standard to 1.

```
df <- scale(mtcars)

apply(df,2,mean)

          mpg           cyl          disp            hp          drat            wt          qsec            vs 
 7.112366e-17 -1.474515e-17 -9.084937e-17  1.040834e-17 -2.918672e-16  4.681043e-17  5.299580e-16  6.938894e-18 
           am          gear          carb 
 4.510281e-17 -3.469447e-18  3.165870e-17 

apply(df,2,sd)

mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

As you can see all variables have zero mean and sd one.

This could avoid using loops.